# Xamarin binding property of base view

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, bindable

I have a base XAML View that have a custom control with bindable property that is used to show/hide a `Grid` control.
I need to change this property from a XAML View that inherit from the base View.

**the custom control view**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Syncfusion.SfBusyIndicator.XForms;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace TEST_SF
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class VolosLoading : ContentView
{
    private static Grid _LoadingContainer = null;

    public bool Mostra
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(MostraProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MostraProperty, value); OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Mostra)); }
    }

    public static BindableProperty MostraProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
       propertyName: nameof(Mostra),
       returnType: typeof(bool),
       declaringType: typeof(VolosLoading),
       defaultValue: false,
       defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay
       , propertyChanged: MostraPropertyChanged
   );

    private static void MostraPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {

        _LoadingContainer.IsEnabled = (bool)newValue;
        _LoadingContainer.IsVisible = (bool)newValue;
    }

    public VolosLoading()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _LoadingContainer = (Grid)FindByName("LoadingContainer");
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Mostra));
    }
 }
}
```

**its view**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:busyindicator="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfBusyIndicator.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfBusyIndicator.XForms"
    x:Class="TEST_SF.VolosLoading">

    <ContentView.Content>        
        <Grid x:Name="LoadingContainer" IsEnabled="{Binding Mostra}" IsVisible="{Binding Mostra}">            
            <Grid BackgroundColor="LightGray" Opacity="0.6" />
            <busyindicator:SfBusyIndicator x:Name="Loading" AnimationType="DoubleCircle" 
                                           ViewBoxWidth="150" ViewBoxHeight="150" 
                                           TextColor="Green" BackgroundColor="Transparent"  
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>

</ContentView>
```

**the base class**

```
   namespace TEST_SF.Base
    {
      public class BaseClass
      {
          public static VolosLoading PageLoading = new VolosLoading { Mostra = false };
      }
    }
```

**the base view**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TEST_SF"
             x:Class="TEST_SF.BasePage">
    <ContentPage.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label BackgroundColor="Red" Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                <local:VolosLoading></local:VolosLoading>

                <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>

            </StackLayout>
        </ControlTemplate>

    </ContentPage.ControlTemplate>
    </ContentPage>
```

Then I have a view that inherit from the base View with a button that calls a command that execute this code:

```
PageLoading.Mostra = !PageLoading.Mostra;
```

The class is:

```
class MainPage_Repo : Base.BaseClass
```

its view:

```
 <local:BasePage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TEST_SF"
             x:Class="TEST_SF.MainPage">

        <ContentPage.BindingContext>
            <local:MainPage_Repo />
        </ContentPage.BindingContext>

            <StackLayout>
                <Button VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Loading SF" Command="{Binding MyMockCommand}" CommandParameter="1" />
            </StackLayout>
    </local:BasePage>
```

The problems are that the `Grid` is visible at start, and when the button is pressed nothing changes, the value of `Mostra` is changed correctly but he `Grid` is always visible.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have static properties in `ContentView`, weird problems are expected to happen, as they are shared across instances, in your case that relates to the `_LoadingContainer`

Even if this doesn't resolve your problem that is something that can cause huge problems and shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you are calling:

```cs
_LoadingContainer = (Grid)FindByName("LoadingContainer");
```

This line is creating a **copy** of the `Grid` container defined in the XAML by `x:Name="LoadingContainer"`. Then, when the `Mostra` property changes, you are then doing:

```cs
_LoadingContainer.IsEnabled = (bool)newValue;
_LoadingContainer.IsVisible = (bool)newValue;
```

The above is accessing and changing the properties of the **copy** of the `Grid` view, not the actual `LoadingContainer` itself.

Replace all instances of `_LoadingContainer` with `LoadingContainer`, and your problem should be solved.

Also, you can remove the bindings to the `IsVisible` and `IsEnabled` properties of the `Grid`. These will cause unnecessary complexity in the compiled code.

**EDIT**

In addition, in your `MostraPropertyChanged` handler, you should change it to the following:

```cs
private static void MostraPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var control = (VolosLoading)bindable;
    if (control != null)
    {
        control.LoadingContainer.IsEnabled = (bool)newValue;
        control.LoadingContainer.IsVisible = (bool)newValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't replace all instances of _LoadingContainer with LoadingContainer, because inside the MostraPropertyChanged method, LoadingContainer doesn't exists.
I would like to use the Binding for IsVisible and IsEnabled inside the XMAL view.

Comment: I've added an edit to my answer, which should cover that. You can access your XAML contents by accessing the `BindableObject` as your control.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't works.
I have also tried to add 'BindingContext = this' after InitializeComponent(), but doesn't works.